# converting a calendar date to a string?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am trying to get the program to call up the current date, add 30 days to it, and then out put that date as a string.

```
        // Set calendar for due date on invoice gui
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Add 30 days to the calendar for the due date
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
    Date dueDate = cal.getTime();
    dueDatestr = Calendar.toString(dueDate);
```

Comment: What's the problem?  That toString() usage looks a bit odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the question is?

If you want to format your date, I suggest looking at [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead of using `toString()`. You can do something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
dueDateStr = dateFormat.format(dueDate); // renders as 11/29/2009
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it:

```
Date dueDate = cal.getTime();
String dueDateAsString = dueDate.toString();
```

or

```
String dueDateAsFormattedString = DateFormat.format(dueDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [FastDateFormat](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html) from Apache commons, instead of SimpleDateFormat, because SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe.

```
FastDateFormat dateFormat = FastDateFormat.getInstance("MM/dd/yyyy");
dueDateStr = dateFormat.format(dueDate);
```

This is especially true if you wanted to use a static instance of the date formatter, which is a common temptation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with a class of mine:
https://github.com/knyttl/Maite/wiki/Maite-Date-and-Time

```
new Time()
    .plus(1, Time.DAY)
    .format("yyyy-MM-dd");
```